# How do I set font size in Visual Studios Diagnostic Tools?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

The font size in the Visual Studio Diagnostic tools window is HUGE compared to the rest of my UI.  Is there any way to set it?

I went all through the categories in `Tools >> Options >> Fonts and Colors` and I could not see anything that affected it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click in the Diagnostics tools window, and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and use your mouse wheel to shrink (or enlarge) the text in the window (similar to how you would in an editor window - I think it's actually just zooming in and out rather than actually changing the font size).

Comment: Oh good grief!  I cannot believe I didn't think of something so obvious.  I use CTRL+Mousewheel all the time in the code window too.  Thank you!

Comment: That would be great if that worked in all VS windows, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Joe I can see it having its uses I suppose.  I'm sure some other windows it works in, but I'm not sure which ones.  To be honest, I literally just learned this information myself after trying - I didn't even think you could zoom in and out in individual windows.

Comment: I suppose they're sort of stuck between the legacy UI, in which we used to control everything through `Tools >> Options >> Fonts and Colors` (and which requires us to find the correct category in a list) and newer UIs that let you use the mouse wheel.