# Is there a way to zoom out all screen on Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

zoom out shortcuts for vs code such as ctrl+shift+- does not work for vs 2022. Is there any way to zoom out specifically in vs 2022 as not only for the editor side in it but for the all screen?

I tried ctrl+shift+- or ctrl+- but those all does not work for vs 2022.

Comment: Tools > Customize > Keyboard button.  Type "View.Zoom" in the 'Show commands' box, select the entries to see the shortcut key.  I don't think every tool window is freely resizable, but never actually tried that.

Comment: Some windows allow you to hold the CTRL key and use your mouse wheel to zoom in and out of the window, such as the [Diagnostic Tools window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73884400/6530134)

Answer (score 0):

View => open Output then increase or decrease the zoom level

Zoom in and Zoom out in the left side of the output window

there is a option called top bar and zoom in the output window